# Insert data into SQl Server Database using ADO.Net Dataset

Tags: ado.net

I have a small database with a table with 2 columns (ID and Name)

I have an ASP.Net form that i want to input an ID and a Name and upon clicking the button, it will insert rows into the database

I want to do this using a dataset. Meaning, I want to add the rows first into a ado.net dataset. Once I have the dataset with its table and rows, I want to insert data into the SQL Server 2008 database using SQLDataAdpater.

I can manually create a DS and add rows in it

How do I accomplish inserting data to database with the dataset I created?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you 
HOW TO: Implement a DataSet SELECT INTO Helper Class in Visual C# .NET
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326009/en